# Need regex for all dynamic category items in node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am working on node.js with regex. I have done the following:

```
 Category 1.2
 Category 1.3 and 1.4
 Category 1.3 to 1.4
 CATEGORY 1.3
```

The regex is

```
((cat|Cat|CAT)(?:s\.|s|S|egory|EGORY|\.)?)(&#xA0;|\s)?((\w+)?([.-]|(&#x2013;)|(&#x2014;))?(\w+))(\s+(to|and)\s(\w+)([.-]|(&#x2013;)|(&#x2014;))(\w+))?
```

However, I need a regex to also match the following strings:

```
 Category 1.2, 1.3 and 1.5
 Category 1.2, 4.5, 2.3 and 1.6
 Category 1.2, 4.5, 2.3, 4.5 and 1.6
 Figure 1.2 and 1.4     - no need
```

How can I find all the category items (1.2,4.5,2.3,4.5 and 1.6) dynamically?Category grows depending on category available.

Note: No need matching `Figure 1.2`.

Any one assist me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend for constructing and testing regular expressions.

Comment: `/category\s\d.\d\s(and|to\s\d.\d)?/i` will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a simplified version of the regex:

```
/cat(?:s?\.?|egory)?[ ]*(?:[ ]*(?:,|and|to)?[ ]*\d(?:\.\d+)?)*/gi
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG5zB2/6)

If you need those hard spaces and en- and em-dashes, you can add them to the regex where necessary, like:

```
/cat(?:s?\.?|egory)?[ —–\xA0]*(?:[ —–\xA0]*(?:,|and|to)?[  —–\xA0]*\d(?:\.\d+)?)*/gi
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG5zB2/7)

Sample code:

```js
    var re = /cat(?:s?\.?|egory)?[ —–\xA0]*(?:[ —–\xA0]*(?:,|and|to)?[  —–\xA0]*\d(?:\.\d+)?)*/gi; 
var str = 'Figure 1.2. Category 1.2 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  Category 1.3 and 1.4 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  Category 1.3 to 1.4 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  CATEGORY 1.3 Figure 1.2. \n\nFigure 1.2.  Category 1.2, 1.3 and 1.5 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  Category 1.2, 4.5, 2.3 and 1.6 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2. Category 1.2, 4.5, 2.3, 4.5 and 1.6 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  Category 1.3 — 1.4 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  Category 1.3 – 1.4 Figure 1.2. \nFigure 1.2.  Category  1.3 – 1.4 Figure 1.2. (with hard space)';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.write("<br>" + m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got interrupted trying to solve this and see stribizhev fixed it for you. Just want to share where I was going:

```
var lines = 
 'Category 1.2\n'+
 'Category 1.3 and 1.4\n'+
 'Category 1.3 to 1.4\n'+
 'CATEGORY 1.3\n'+
 'Category 1.2, 1.3 and 1.5\n'+
 'Category 1.2, 4.5, 2.3 and 1.6\n'+
 'Category 1.2, 4.5, 2.3, 4.5 and 1.6\n'+
 'Figure 1.2 and 1.4\n'

document.write(lines.replace(/^(?!category).*$/igm, '').match(/(\d+\.\d+)/gm));
```

This snippet removes all lines not containing the word 'category' (lines like 'Figure...') - the `replace` - and then matches all categories (a number - full stop - number) and gives them in an array.

I know your regex is much more complex than this, but this seem to do what you asked for and is very simple... Just sharing ;)

Regards